# Check Fields are filled otherwise display error in php

Tags: php, mysql

in this i have to check if in fields data is fields then it submit otherwise it can display error with if statements

```
   <?php
include("config.php");
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $phone=$_POST["phone"];
    $budget=$_POST['budget'];
        $insert_query="insert into form(name,email,phone,budget) values ('$name','$email','$phone','$budget')";
        $con=mysql_query($insert_query);

   ?>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: this code have Sqlinjection bug.!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at empty() function
http://php.net/empty

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     die('name is empty');
}
```

Comment: i have to do this for all fields

Comment: each field you dont want to be empty you need to check if its empty.. very simple

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

thispage.php

```
<?php

$name = (empty($_GET['name'])) ? "Fred" : $_GET['name'];

echo $name;

?>
```

thispage.php       = 'Fred'

thispage.php?Wilma = 'Wilma'

And usual caveats about sql injection, prepared statements, deprecated methods, etc.

Answer (score -1):

First you MUST clean post fields before writing in db. Use function `mysql_real_escape_string($var)`
And second, you can check field data with function `empty`, for example:

```
if (!empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
    // your query
} else {
    echo 'Name is empty!';
}
```

Comment: i have to do this for all fields

Comment: mysql_ methods are deprecated. We probably should not be promoting their use!

Comment: We must promote mysqli functions, but mysqli support is not exists on some servers